# CLASSPATH 101... (on Windows)

Tags: java, classpath

I'm new to working with Java from the command line and I don't get it. I read previous CLASSPATH questions but still didn't get my problem to work.

I have the following class in C:\Temp\a\b\c

```
package a.b.c;

public class Hello
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

The package name is intentional.
I compiled it fine and I put the Hello.class file inside C:\Temp\a\target

Now in the command line I go to C:\Temp\ and execute the following:

```
java -cp .\a\target a.b.c.Hello
```

It complains that it cannot find the class a.b.c.Hello

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try java -cp a/target a.b.c.Hello

Answer (score 3):

> and I put the Hello.class file inside C:\Temp\a\target

This is wrong. It should be placed in the same folder as the `.java` file. The source code itself is declared to be in the `package a.b.c;` so, the `.class` file should really be kept in `\a\b\c` folder.

Then, to execute it just do:

```
C:\Temp>java -cp . a.b.c.Hello
```

Comment: I do it intentionally because other projects I'm working on don't have the class files in the same folder as the source files. I'm trying to learn from this simple example for the bigger projects.

Comment: Then you need to change the `package` declaration of the code to match `a.target`.

Comment: Well, not necessarily in the *same* folder, but in the same folder structure.

Comment: Yes, it is working now after I fixed the src and target to have the same folder structure. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, don't forget to mark the most helpful answer to accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid "putting" the classfiles anywhere. The following should work:

```
javac -d c:\temp c:\temp\a\b\c\Hello.java
# creates Hello.class in c:\temp\a\b\c
java -cp c:\temp a.b.c.Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Java will try to search for a directory structure `a\b\c` from starting in `target` and as you notice, it wont work.

Move the whole directory into `target` and you'll be fine, it should look like:

```
 C:\Temp\a\target\a\b\c\Hello.class
```

You may compile it with the -d option which tall the compiler where to put the class file.

Many project structures are like this.

```
C:\whatever\projectname\src
C:\whatever\projectname\classes
C:\whatever\projectname\bin
C:\whatever\projectname\lib
C:\whatever\projectname\doc
```

That way you can always step on your project directory and type:

```
javac -d classes src\*.java
```

Which will compile all the sources in the `src` directory and will place them in the `classes` directory.

Then execute your program:

```
java -cp classes a.b.c.Hello
```

You may optionally place required jars in `lib`

This works pretty fine for small programs ( < 10 src files and 2 - 3 jar libraries ) If it grows beyond that, you could probably use an IDE or ant

The good thing about following this project structure is that some IDES ( as IntellJ idea ) just pick them very easily when you create a new project. You select "Create project from existing sources"  and then you can continue from there.

I like compiling and editing at the command line a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on BalusC's point: the classpath defines a "root".  When java is looking for your classes, it will start at each root (or jar) in your class path and drill down through the directories to match the package strucutre.  You still need to have you class in a directory structure that matches its package name.  In your case, to execute

java -cp .\a\target a.b.c.Hello

you would move the file to

.\a\target\a\b\c\Hello.class

Years ago, I too found this baffling.